# Display site title on every page other than the home page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make it so when my visitors visit my homepage, my site title is NOT visible. Then, I would like it to be visible on every other page.

What kind of CSS would I need to do something like this?

Site: www.visualicreative.com

Comment: 1. Why would you want to do this? 2. This is not something you can do in CSS. CSS has no idea whether it's on your homepage or not.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "site title" are you referring to the `<title>` tag in your `<head>` or to some heading/text title on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct in thinking you mean the contents of `<h1 id="site-title">...</h1>` are what you want hidden only on the homepage, then you can do the following:

```
body.home #site-title {
   display: none;
}
```

WordPress adds some helpful classes to the body element, one of which is "home" when you're on the home page. You can use this to style things differently on the home page.

Comment: If you're referring to the `<title></title>` element in the HTML file, however, then the other commenters are correct - that's not something you can get rid of via CSS.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Even though I understand it's not the proper way to format this, this code worked for my purpose. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Just so you are aware, Wordpress has built-in methods for things like this. While the method above does technically work, a better practice would be to utilize the `is_home()` function in a conditional statement to prevent the title from being displayed when the home page is the current page. If your home page is significantly different from other posts or pages, it might also be a good idea to create a template for the home page with the correct filename, see: `http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove/hide an element within the `<body>` of your homepage using CSS, then you can use the following CSS:

```
body.home .title {
    display: none;
}
```

If you're trying to remove, or better yet alter the `<title>` tag of the homepage, you can edit your theme's `header.php` file to use the following code:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
    <title>Homepage Title</title>
<?php } else { ?>
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

site title tag isn't something a css can change... for whatever weird reason you want to do this... use SEO Yoast

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/